# PHP Quiz System

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a PHP Quiz System which displays all questions on one page.
The following is my code.

**PHP**

```
$getQ = mysqli_query($condb, "select * from questions where eid = '$exam'");
        if($getQ){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($getQ)==0){
                $summaryLink = 'examSummary.php?exam='.$exam;
                redirect($summaryLink);
            }
```

**Form**

```
<?php while($ans = mysqli_fetch_array($getQ)){  ?>
    <div class="ques" id="ques">
        <input type="hidden" name="exam" value="<?php echo $exam; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value="<?php echo $ans['qid'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['sid']; ?>">   
    
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="answer" onChange="update();">
            <label for="<?php echo $ans['option_1'];?>"><?php echo $ans['option_1'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="answer" onChange="update();">
            <label for="<?php echo $ans['option_2'];?>"><?php echo $ans['option_2'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="answer" onChange="update();">
            <label for="<?php echo $ans['option_3'];?>"><?php echo $ans['option_3'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="answer" onChange="update();">
            <label for="<?php echo $ans['option_4'];?>"><?php echo $ans['option_4'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="answer" onChange="update();">
            <label for="<?php echo $ans['option_5'];?>"><?php echo $ans['option_5'];?></label>
        </p>
        <div class="status2"></div>
```

What I want to do is, once the user select an answer for a questions, the selected option and few other hidden form data (`qid, eid, sid`) should be passed to `updateAnswer.php`
`updateAnswer.php` will update the selected answer to the database.
I tired the following jQuery. But it wont do anything.

```
<script>
    function update() {
     var radVal = $("input[type=radio][name=answer]:checked").val();    
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "updateAnswer.php",
        data:'eid='+$("#eid").val()+'&sid='+$("#sid").val()+'&qid='+$("#qid").val()+'&answer='+$(radVal).val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $(".status2").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
    }
    </script>
```

The system should pass data to `updateAnswer.php` when a user clicks on an option(answer).

But with my current code, when a user clicks on an option won't do anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details as to exactly how your code is not working in the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Nick - Done. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Have you checked whether `valid` is true? Also in `updateAnswer.php`, have you checked that what you expect to be in `$_POST` is actually there?

Comment: @Nick No I haven't. If `updateAnswer.php` got nothing an error message displays. But in my case nothing returns to `<div class="status2"></div>`

Comment: If `updateAnswer.php` fails for any reason, you'll never know on the client as there is no code in your error handler. It might be worth adding something there e.g. `$(".status2").html(<p style="color:red">Error from ajax call</p>');` (you can also get the message in the `textStatus` parameter to the error callback).

Comment: Added. But still not displaying any error

Comment: So what about `valid`? is it actually true so that the ajax call happens?

Comment: @Nick - Sorry it is a mistake. I removed the valid. It is not necessary. But still no good news.

Comment: A couple of other issues I can see: you don't seem to have an element with `id="eid"`. Also, `$(radVal).val()` in the generation of `data` should just be `radVal`. And all your radio buttons have `id="answer"` which is not valid HTML

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some mistakes in your code, first one is that the `id` should always be unique, so before your `while loop` take a variable and initialize it to zero and `increment` it on every `iteration`; You can use this variable and append after every `id` to make it unique. Like so -

```
<?php 

$i = 0;

while(bla bla){

$i++;

?> 
    <!-- You can also use question id here ↓↓ which should be unique -->
    <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="<?php echo "qid".$i; ?>" value="<?php echo $ans['qid'];?>">
    <!-- session id will be the same  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['sid']; ?>">
    <!-- same for others  -->
<?php 

}

?>
```

You also need to give this(`$i` or `question-id`(whichever you choose)) as an `attribute` to `radio buttons` to identify which question id we need to get and on `update function` you need to pass the current checked element, like so -

```
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
<!-- same for others  -->
```

I've created a working snippet for your problem(without `PHP` and `AJAX` of course). I've given them unique `id` and `values`, I'm printing the desired values on the `console`. I've changed the `AJAX` code as well, you can use it in your code to check if it works. Comments are mentioned wherever necessary, see if it helps you.

```js
function update(element) {
  
  let answer = $(element).val(); // get the value of checked element
  let id = $(element).attr('data-id'); // get id of the radio button clicked
  let eid = $('#eid').val(); // exam id will be same for all the questions
  let sid = $('#sid').val(); // session id will be same
  let qid = $('#qid' + id).val(); // get question id
  
  // send ajax request
  /*jQuery.ajax({
    url: "updateAnswer.php",
    data: 'eid=' + eid + '&sid=' + sid + '&qid=' + qid + '&answer=' + answer,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#status' + id).html(data); // show status on the related div
    },
    error: function() {}
  });*/
  console.clear();
  console.log(`id: ${id}, eid: ${eid}, sid: ${sid}, qid: ${qid}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ques" id="ques1">
  <input type="hidden" name="exam" value="some_exam" id="some_exam">
  <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="some_examid" id="eid">
  <!-- question id 1 (use php) -->
  <input type="hidden" name="question" id="question1" value="question1">
  <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid1" value="qid1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="some_session">

  <p>
    <!-- Give question id in data-id attribute (use php) and pass current element in update function -->
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="1">
    <label>option_1_1</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="1">
    <label>option_1_2</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="1">
    <label>option_1_3</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="1">
    <label>option_1_4</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="1">
    <label>option_1_5</label>
  </p>
  <div class="status2" id="status1"></div>
  ---------------------------------------
  <!-- Second question starts (incremet i)-->
  ---------------------------------------
  <div class="ques" id="ques2">
    <input type="hidden" name="exam" value="some_exam" id="some_exam">
    <input type="hidden" name="eid" value="some_examid" id="eid">
    <input type="hidden" name="question" id="question2" value="question1">
    <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid2" value="qid2">
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="some_session">

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="option_2_1" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="2">
      <label>option_2_1</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="2">
      <label>option_2_2</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="2">
      <label>option_2_3</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="2">
      <label>option_2_4</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" class="answer" onChange="update(this);" data-id="2">
      <label>option_2_5</label>
    </p>
    <div class="status2" id="status2"></div>
```